# Resetting a form after submit

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I have a form which if the email is wrong gives me an error message while i stay on the same page, this is possible because i used ajax. Now I'm trying to achieve when i submit the form and the return is an error that the forms reset.

I tried `reset();` but it didn't work.

```
<?php
    header("Refresh:7; url=contact.php");
    $email = $_POST['subscribefield'];

    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        echo "Dit emailadres klopt niet";
      reset($email);
    }


    $to = "flash1996mph@hotmail.com";
    $subject = "Abonee voor de nieuwsbrief";
    $body = "$email \n Heeft zich aangemeld voor de nieuwsbrief";

    mail($to, $subject, $body);
    echo "U heeft zich zojuist aangemeld voor de vandenberg nieuwsbrief";
?>
```

and

```
$('form.subscribe').on('submit', function() {
    var that = $(this),
    url = that.attr('action'),
    method = that.attr('method'),
    data = {};

    that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {
        var that = $(this),
        name = that.attr('name'),
        value = that.val();

        data[name] = value;
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type:method,
        data: data,
        success: function(response) {
            $('#success-message').html(response).show();
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#success-message').fadeOut('slow');
            }, 2000); 
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Did you read the PHP manual, what the reset function does?  *Set the internal pointer of an array to its first element* And anyway, I think you want to add an `event.preventDefault();` on form submit, and add event as a parameter to that js function.

Comment: If what you want to do is to delete the POST email variable, use `unset($_POST['subscribefield'])` instead. And if you want to reset the form values: try `$('.form.subscribe')[0].reset();`

Comment: @NachoM. neither are working ;_;

Comment: @kevinseda So, if what you really want to do is to empty the form values try: `$(':input','form.subscribe')
 .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
 .val('')
 .removeAttr('checked')
 .removeAttr('selected');
`

Comment: Yeah, that worked :D @NachoM.

Comment: I put it as an answer @kevinseda to allow you to close the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you really want to do is to empty the form values try:

```
$(':input','form.subscribe')
 .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
 .val('') .removeAttr('checked')
 .removeAttr('selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this button inside your `<form>`:

```
<input type="reset" value="Reset Form" id="resetButton" >
```

and make a click on this button whenever you find error in return like this,

```
$("#resetButton").click();
```

Comment: what will happen to my submit button

Answer (score 0):

I do something like if the ajax call was success, but something went wrong, then reset the form on the **client side**.

For example:

```
success: function(resp) {
    // if the form is invalid
    if (resp.invalid) {
        // find your elems
        $('#myForm').find('input[type=text]').val("");
    }
}
```

On the other hand you should validate the form firstly on the client side then on the server too.  For example [this library](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) can be very useful.